# How could I change the scrollbars colors on Plasma(5.16) on Kubuntu 19.10?

Tags: kubuntu, gui, plasma

I'm a Kubuntu 19.10 user and I would like to change the scrollbars colors, and width if possible, on this distro which uses Plasma 5.16, any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Thank you !

Comment: The *Oxygen* application style has a slider for scrollbar width (min 10px; max 30px). This will apply to your `qt` applications. Another route is to install `qtcurve` and use the *qtcurve* application style. `qtcurve` has innumerable customization options, including scrollbar width and color settings, which you can explore.

Comment: Thank you man! QTCurve was what I wanted! for those like me who like to tinker, here is the URL of QTCurve, in there you could find the building and installation instructions: https://github.com/KDE/qtcurve

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, `qtcurve` is in the Universe repository. Of course, it maybe an older version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DK Bose comment was the solution I wanted.

The approach I took was:

1. I tried the Oxygen application style in Plasma's System Settings application. I found I could change scrollbar width but not color.
2. Then I decided to give QTCurve a try. This involved building from source on my machine. Beware: if you are not a developer or user with a tinkerer spirit this could be difficult for you. This step involved cloning QTCurve Github repo from https://github.com/KDE/qtcurve, compiling and then installing on my machine. The compiling process needs some development packages from KDE (for libraries and such) which I already had because I'm compiling KDE apps from source. Once I did all of that I went to System Settings application and in there I found the new QTCurve I just built. QTCurve has a lot of options, and the scrollbars have the width and color customization I wanted!

Comment: We don't close questions which have been "Solved". Instead, after a couple of days, you can click the ✔ to the left of your answer to mark it "Accepted". This site encourages users to answer their own questions.