# How to change the color of the scrollbar and slider in Kubuntu 20.4 systemwide

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, colors, plasma-5, scrollbar

I want to change the colors of my scrollbar and slider systemwide. I already changed the width to my liking, but have no such luck with the colors.

Looked around on this forum and searched for widgets, but can't seem to find the solution. I played around in `.config/gtk-3.0/colors.css` and `config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`, but that only changed things in gtk-3.0 applications (which is normal).

I want the changes to be systemwide though.

---

I use:

- OS: Kubuntu 20.04
- KDE Plasma-version: 5.18.5
- Version van KDE-Frameworks: 5.68.0
- Qt-version: 5.12.8
- Kernel-version: 5.11.0-38-generic
- Type OS: 64-bit
- Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
- Geheugen: 15,3 GiB RAM

in triple boot with Win10 (Yeah, I know) and Mint 20.1 Ulyssa Cinnamon on a laptop.

edit 221021-1534
I looked at a post from Julian Borrero, which is for 19.10, but can't get that to work. [How could I change the scrollbars colors on Plasma(5.16) on Kubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222418/how-could-i-change-the-scrollbars-colors-on-plasma5-16-on-kubuntu-19-10). My result was an error.log with 8 times

> Compiling the Fortran compiler identification source file "CMakeFortranCompilerId.F" failed.
> Compiler: CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER-NOTFOUND
> Build flags:
> Id flags: -v

The output was:
No such file or directory.

This is all new to me. I have a qtcurve.zip ( from Github ) in my `downloads`folder. Where do I put this? Do I unpack it? I have `cmake` and `cmake-3.16`folders in `user/share`.

My `/home` is a seperate partition btw, although I think that this doesn't matter at the moment.

Comment: What do you mean with "systemwide"? Usually it means "for all users" which is not possible, since this are per user settings. I believe you mean "for all applications, not only GTK", am I correct?

Comment: @ mook765 Yes, that is what I mean. But since I am the only user what I want will be for all applications and systemwide, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you stumbled upon `qtcurve` in the question you linked, you just need to know, that you don't need to compile it yourself, in 20.04 the package exists in the official repositories and can be easily installed with

```
sudo apt install qtcurve
```

After installation, go to `System Settings`>`Appearance`>`Application Style`, choose the new application style "QtCurve" and edit it's settings.

[image]

[image]

After making your changes, close the editor window with the `OK`-button and then `Apply` your changes in the System Settings window.

Note that this will affect only native KDE applications which are based on Qt. It will not affect applications based on GTK.

Comment: That's great, thank you so much. Got it and played around in it. Love it!!