# How to change the shut down and boot up logo in Kubuntu 21.10?

Tags: kubuntu

I'm presently trying to move over to linux as my OS, rather than windows. My wife has been using Kubuntu for quite a while now. Anyways...

The one thing I really like about Kubuntu is customizing to 'make it mine' type thing.

My question is, how do you change the boot up and shut down logo's ?

I've looked online but the info seems older or a bit sketchy, so I figured I'd see if I figured I'd ask here to get the most update information on how to do this.

Thanks ahead of time for any all responses/help...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, hope Linux people build a terminology to make easy to find a name of everything.  It's called plymouth. https://askubuntu.com/questions/132120/how-to-recover-splash-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://askubuntu.com/questions/12394/getting-back-ubuntus-default-boot-splash?noredirect=1&lq=1 These are the link of recoveries but it can apply for replacing new one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings --->system settings --->startup and shutdown --->splash screen. There you can change it. See picture [image]. You can download lots of them ( button right below `get new splash screens`). 
If you download `qt-curve` you can even change more settings than 'standard'-kde changes ( e.g. slidebar color/width). Almost endless possibilities. See picture [image]. 
Enjoy YOUR desktop in Kubuntu. If you like the answer please accept it.

Comment: Hello - I appreciate the info, but I was actually talking about the logo that appears when everything is loading up before the log in screen and after you choose to shut down/log-off, etc.

Comment: Also, thanks for the gt-curve tip, I'm going to try and locate it, install it, etc...

Comment: I don't have a logo that appears before seeing the ```grub-menu``` (triple boot Kubuntu, Mint & Win10), nor when I shutdown Kubuntu. Btw it is Qt-Curve. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370879/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-scrollbar-and-slider-in-kubuntu-20-4-systemwide on how to install it.

Comment: QT-Curve installed - thanks for the help, it's much appreciated. When my kubuntu loads up I get a Kubuntu logo wit the glow effect and when I shut down I get a Kubuntu logo. Those are the two I was hoping to swap out for an alien head or something for the hey of it. No biggy though, just a fun/customize thing. Thanks again.